# Connect to node.js socket.io server: clients don't connect - server reports" destroying non-socket.io upgrade"

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I thought that socket.io would allow me to implement a websocket server.  I have this very simple code:

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http'), io = require('socket.io');

// start at port 8888
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text\html'});
    res.end('<h1>Welcome to the Notification Server</h1>'); 
});
server.listen(8888);

// Create Socket.io obj/pass to server
var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Successful Websocket connection!');

    client.on('message', function(event) {
        console.log("Received message from client", event);     
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('Client has disconnected');
    });
});
```

I've tried a few different test clients all of which generate this message on the server:  **debug - destroying non-socket.io upgrade**

One such client attempt has some code like this:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!---
window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://dev.ourserver.com:8888");

ws.onopen = function() {
    alert("Connected");
}

ws.onerror = function(error) {
    alert("Error:"+error);
}

// -->
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as we load the page I get the debug message on the server.

I thought the point of this library was to support the websocket protocol and any client supporting websockets would be able to connect.

If I interpret the message literally it seems to indicate that server.io has detected that it is connecting to a "non socket.io" client.  Does this mean that there is no way for me to connect to this server without using socket.io in the client?

Comment: Your `Received message from client` case refers to an `event` that isn't passed as a parameter -- is this intentional? Is this the actual code that's having trouble?

Comment: Thanks, yes that is some missing code, but the issue is that a connection is never made at the moment, so that mistake is not related to question.

Comment: Oh? I thought the following line meant that you _did_ get the connection from the client: _As soon as we load the page I get the debug message on the server._. Can you post a single self-contained program that will show the whole problem from start to finish?

Comment: @sarnold I updated the question with a minimal client, to illustrate the problem.  It "connects" but then the server immediately issues the error and disconnects.

Comment: Neat, reproduced here when I visit the client page at `file:///tmp/client.html`. But if I put the client's contents into the `end()`, I don't get the `debug` message -- nor do I get any errors in Firefox's console. I just don't get the JS `alert()` boxes. Still, I've gotta think that you need to use the same server to handle both the WS connections and the HTML that loads the client-side WS.

Comment: yeah I was wondering if this was a cross domain issue, although a bit of googling on the idea seemed to indicate that websockets is inherently suppossed to allow it, and socket.io is as well.  I guess I need to dash off a quick socket.io client to see.

Comment: After doing some more experimenting, i changed the client code to console.log(ws) and what I see is that onopen and onclose methods of the object are null.  So it looks to me like the current WebSocket library simply will not connect to the socket.io server.